# Optimize with constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

I want to find the smallest $k$ such that $kx^2 \ge (\sin(x)-x)^2$ for all scalar $x\in[a,\ b]$? Obviously, I can do it analytically, but how can I do it (symbolically) in Mathematica? I am new to Mathematica and I am not really familiar with it.

Comment: Have a look at `Minimize`: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html

Comment: I do not understand how to write "Minimize $k$ such that $g(k,x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ in the given range. How to set this constraint in Minimize?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** I think you need MinMax.

How about this?

```
NMaximize[{(x^2 - 2 x Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2)/x^2, 4 <= x <= 5}, x]
```

> {1.48166, {x -> 4.49341}}

So   $ k=1.48166$

```
RegionPlot[k x^2 >= (Sin[x] - x)^2, {x, -10, 10}, {k, -10, 10}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "k"}, Axes -> True, 
 GridLines -> {None, {1.48166}}, GridLinesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Your problem is equivalent to finding root of derivative of $\frac{(\sin (x)-x)^2}{x^2}$

```
  D[(Sin[x] - x)^2/x^2, x] // Simplify
```

> $\frac{2 (\sin (x)-x) (x \cos (x)-\sin (x))}{x^3}=0$

Which is equivalent to

```
Solve[{Tan[x] - x == 0, 4 <= x <= 5}, x] // N
```

> {{x -> 4.49341}}

**Original Answer:**

RHS is positive and thus $k\nless0$. Therefore $k=0$ is the smallest value.

```
   RegionPlot[k x^2 >= (Sin[x] - x)^2, {x, -10, 10}, {k, -10, 10}, 
     FrameLabel -> {"x", "k"}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
Minimize[{1, k x^2 >= (Sin[x] - x)^2}, {k, x}]
```

> {1, {k -> 0, x -> 0}}

```
Minimize[{1, k x^2 >= (Sin[x] - x)^2}, k]
```

$\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & (\sin (x)=0\land x=0)\lor (\sin (x)=0\land x>0)\lor (\sin (x)=0\land x<0)\lor (\sin (x)>0\land x>0)\lor (\sin (x)>0\land x<0)\lor (\sin
   (x)<0\land x>0)\lor (\sin (x)<0\land x<0) \\
 \infty  & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\left\{k\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & (\sin (x)=0\land x>0)\lor (\sin (x)=0\land x<0) \\
 \frac{2 x^2-2 \sin (x) x+\sin ^2(x)}{x^2} & (\sin (x)>0\land x>0)\lor (\sin (x)>0\land x<0)\lor (\sin (x)<0\land x>0)\lor (\sin (x)<0\land x<0) \\
 0 & \sin (x)=0\land x=0 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right\}\right\}$

Comment: The constraint should be satisfied for all $x$ in the interval, thus $k=0$ is obviously wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide such $x\in[a,b]$ so that $k=0$ is wrong?

Comment: Let $a=0$, $b=2$ and choose $x=1$. Then $kx^2=k$ and $(\sin(x)-x)^2 \approx 0.025$. The inequality $kx^2 \ge (\sin(x)-x)^2$ is not satisfied for $k<0.025$.

Comment: You minimized `1` rather than `k`. `Minimize` doesn't work with `k`; however, you can use `NMinimize`: `NMinimize[{k, k x^2 >= (Sin[x] - x)^2}, {k, x}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon How can I specify that the constraint should be satisfied only for the given range $x \in [a,\ b]$?

Comment: For specific numeric values of `{a, b}` use `NMinimize[{k, k x^2 >= (Sin[x] - x)^2, a <= x <= b}, {k, x}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Sorry, but it does not work for me. It is straightforward to show that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the answer is $k = 1+\frac{2}{3\pi}$ that is achieved for $x=\frac{3}{2}\pi$. I failed to get the same solution with your code.

Comment: @Aratas your values give False `With[{k = 1 + 2/(3 \[Pi]), x = 3/2 \[Pi]}, {k x^2, (Sin[x] - x)^2}] //  N`  `{26.919, 32.6314}`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Sorry, it is $k = \left(1+\frac{2}{3\pi}\right)^2$.

Comment: @Arastas Your $k$ doesn't work for some $x$ `With[{k = (1 + 2/(3 \[Pi]))^2}, 
 Table[{k x^2 >= (Sin[x] - x)^2, x}, {x, 4, 5, 0.1}]]` `{{True, 4.}, {True, 4.1}, {True, 4.2}, {False, 4.3}, {False, 
  4.4}, {False, 4.5}, {False, 4.6}, {False, 4.7}, {True, 4.8}, {True, 
  4.9}, {True, 5.}}`

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, it implies that I have to do something with the constrains. I am more curious to see if I can specify to Mathematica the constrain $g(k,x)\ge 0$ for all $a\le x \le b$ and not necessary for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the expansion of Sin[x] around x=0. It starts with x. So the subtraction of x compensates for that. The idea with small x is apparently meant
by the authors of this task. The second term in the expansion is since Sin is antisymmetric around x=0 x^3. So k is for some open surrounding of x=0 approximately the second order coefficient of the expansion of Sin around x=0.[image]

So Sin[x] approx. x - x^3/3! + x^6/6! .+ ... . Convergence for the complete power
series if infinity on the real numbers. So compare kx^2 with -x^3/6 which is always true for positive real numbers and limited for negative once since -x^3/6 gets positive.

The situation changes a bit for this task, because the cubic term is squared before comparison. Make yourself a different idea than that already given is the other discussions. Only the parabolas are a band with the linear occuring parameter k.

So draw (Sin[x] - x)^2 and kx^2 for k from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.05 or so and expand the interval around x=0 for increasing k. Both curves are symmetric for x=0. Some 
idea can be to replace k=l^2 and linearize the tasks. The monotonies of both side
grant that there is a crossing. l(x)=(Sin[x]-x)/x=Sin[x]/x-1 approx. x^2/6 +O(x^5) still for small x.

Comment: Thanks. However, as I told in the message, it is not a big deal to find the solution. However, I am more interested in how to do it Mathematica.